# Angular table doesn't show data every few browser reloads

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two model classes: **College** and **Student** that look like this:
**Model classes:**

```
interface College{
    id?: number;
    name: string;
}


export interface Student{
    id?: number;
    name: string;
    collegeId?: number; //Foreign key in database
    collegeName?: Observable<string>; //This property not exists in database
}
```

**Component class initialization**

```
export class StudentComponent implements OnInit {

  private listOfStudents: FormArray = this.formBuilder.array([]);
  private listOfColleges: College[] = [];


constructor(private studentService: StudentService, private collegeService: CollegeService,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getCollegesToList();
    this.getStudentsToList();
  }
```

What I am trying to do is first load all Colleges, then load all Students and while I'm loading students I want to find College name by Student.collegeId property from firstly loaded array of Colleges. It looks like this:
**Component class logic**

```
getCollegesToList() {
    this.collegeService.getAll().subscribe(
      (res: College[]) => {
        res.forEach((col: College) => {
          this.listOfColleges.push({
            id: col.id,
            name: col.name
          });
        })
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
}

getStudentsToList(){
    this.studentService.getAll().subscribe(
      res => {
        (res as Student[]).forEach((stud: Student) => {
          this.listOfStudents.push(this.formBuilder.group({
            id: [stud.id],
            name: [stud.name, Validators.required],
            collegeId: [stud.collegeId],
            collegeName: [this.findCollegeName(stud.collegeId)]
          }));
        })
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
}

findCollegeName(id: number): Observable<string> {
    const FOUND = this.listOfColleges.find(res =>
      res.id == id)
    if (FOUND == null) {
      return of('');
    }
    return of(FOUND.name);
}
```

**Template**

```
<tbody [formGroup]="student" *ngFor="let student of listOfStudents.controls; let i=index;">
                        <tr class="clickable">
                            <th class="numberH" scope="row">{{i+1}}</th>
                            <td class="idH">{{student.value.id}}</td>
                            <td>{{student.value.name}}</td>
                            <td class="text-center">{{student.value.collegeName? (student.value.collegeName | async) : '-'}}</td> //Problem occurs here
                              ...
```

**PROBLEM:** Every let's say 6,7,8 reloads I get no data at all in my *Student.collegeName* table row. I'm using chrome but happens also on Microsoft Edge.
It also doesn't write '-' which I wrote in conditional pipe.

- What is the best practice to fetch such data?

Answer (score 0):

This might happen due to async calls. The response of students lists' might be received earlier than the college's response. You can call getStudentsToList() in success of getCollegesToList(). Your code will be modified as

```
   ngOnInit(){
       this.getCollegesToList();
   }
   getCollegesToList(){
       this.collegeService.getAll().subscribe({
          ..........
          this.getStudentsToList();
       })
   }
```